# core.js:3864 ERROR TypeError: this.datepicker.open is not a function?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, typeerror, angular9

I am using angular material "Basic date range picker" it gives this error. It gives me this error when I click datepicker.

I have used [Text](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pldenpoeymn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.ts) code example.

core.js:3864 ERROR TypeError: this.datepicker.open is not a function
at MatDatepickerToggle.push../node_modules/@angular/material/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm5/datepicker.js.MatDatepickerToggle._open (datepicker.js:2733)
at MatDatepickerToggle_Template_button_click_0_listener

Comment: Please show us your code, not the example you've used.

Comment: make sure , version of material and other required dependencies are installed as used in example

Comment: @LogicBlower There was a version problem. thank you!